# Get max and min values based of daily data based on dates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many days data on it and i wan to obtain hte max and min per day but im getting the same df as the start showing an hour value. The original df looks like this:

```
                  date temperature
1: 2006-04-17 00:00:00    12.67833
2: 2006-04-17 01:00:00    12.14133
3: 2006-04-17 02:00:00    10.36833
4: 2006-04-17 03:00:00    10.78600
5: 2006-04-17 04:00:00    10.76967
6: 2006-04-17 05:00:00    10.92467
```

And im getting this:

```
                  date      Max      Min
1: 2006-04-17 00:00:00 12.67833 12.67833
2: 2006-04-17 01:00:00 12.14133 12.14133
3: 2006-04-17 02:00:00 10.36833 10.36833
4: 2006-04-17 03:00:00 10.78600 10.78600
5: 2006-04-17 04:00:00 10.76967 10.76967
6: 2006-04-17 05:00:00 10.92467 10.92467
```

Im using the next code:

```
library(lubridate)
datatemp<- read.csv("04_2006.csv", header = T)
datatemp$date_time<-parse_date_time(datatemp$date_time,orders = "mdy HMS")
temp_aveg<-aggregate(list(temperature = datatemp$temp), 
          list(date = cut(datatemp$date_time, "1 hour")), 
          mean)
library(data.table)
Tmaxmin<-setDT(temp_aveg)[, list(Max=max(temperature), Min=min(temperature)), by=list(date)]
```

I dont know what im missing?

Comment: Are you getting the `mean` per day or 1 hour interval?

Comment: The mean is per hour interval, after that i want to find the max and min per day based on the 24 points of data stimated before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping on the both the date and the time rather than just the date.
A solution using `lubridate` and `dplyr`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)    

datatemp$date <- date(datatemp$date_time)
datatemp <- na.omit(datatemp)
output <- datatemp %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(max_val = max(temperature),
            min_val = min(temperature))
```

Comment: Well this partially works but in some parts of the dataset i have NA values and im getting this as result, is there a way to avoid getting NA values?

Comment: See updated answer with `na.omit`. This will remove all rows that have an `NA` value in the date time field or the temperature field.